# problem installing ubuntu any version

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to install ubuntu on my laptop(fujitsu Amilo M3438) but each time its either I get a dark screen saying [failde to idle channel with sum numbers written also]and it stops. Or it stops about the final piont of the installation of which I can boot it but it will get interupted with the same problem after 10minutes and stops. I tried installing Mint but it said corrupt kernel image, Kali installs perfectly but shows the same message after a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with certain Nvidia cards and affects both proprietary and Noveau drivers. The only resolution I have found to this problem is to try boot with extra options. At the boot screen, hit 'e' over the Ubuntu selection. Then, find the line that end in "quiet splash." Add one or both of the following to the end of that line:

1. vram_pushbuf=1
2. Either agpmode=0 or agpmode=2

This seems to have fixed it for some people, but not for others.

Here are some relevant bug reports I've found on the issue: [bug report 1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-raring/+bug/1097178), [bug report 2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-nouveau/+bug/1313402), [bug report 3](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=70388).

Answer (score 0):

I had problems too installing linux on a machine with Nvidia video cards. I was getting pixel garbage everytime i should have been getting a display.

What i did was to boot on the cd image then press shift on the ubuntu splash screen right before the installation starts. It let me select a language and then selecting the "nomode" option in the F5-F6 menu (last one, i forget which) let me install ubuntu 14.04.

Trying to help.